# Disabling or hiding stylesheets, how do you do it?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a website that has to run entirely out of one window - it can never load another page. Consequently, I'm using a lot of JS to swap out the content that is displayed on the screen, and it's actually working rather well. However, I'm running out of good selectors and I don't want my stylesheet to get to be excessively long. So, I am wondering: is it possible to disable a stylesheet by placing it inside a `div` that is set to `display:none`?

For example:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <style type="text/css">
        #my_image{
            height:100px;
            background-color:red;
        }
    </style>
</div>
<style type="text/css">
    #my_image{
        height:30px;
    }
</style>
```

In this scenario, which of these would apply? I know that if both are loaded, the second one will be the latest one so it will be the one that is read. But let's say the `div` is not colored at all from the start. Would it be red when this script is run?

If this is not a viable solution to disable styles, then please inform me of what is.

Comment: to disable a stylesheet, you need to remove it, not just stuff it into a hidden div. style sheets aren't "display" material, so "hiding" them inside a div doesn't disable them.

Comment: @MarcB So what is the methodology for disabling them. I've messed around with this in the past and I can never get it to work correctly. When I set it with JS is it `elem.disabled = true;` or `elem.disabled =  'true'` or `elem.disabled = "disabled"`

Comment: Your css is poorly designed if you need to disable it. Use proper id selectors and cascading inheritance to ensure only the right themes are processed. Using something like `<body id="theme1">` and then styling according to that, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should ideally be using a separate stylesheet for each of your "themes".

You could then only load the correct stylesheet at runtime or:

- Use javascript to create / destroy css link elements in the head
- Use javascript to add a class to the body tag 'red' or 'blue' etc. Then have every selector in your theme begin with that class name:

  .blue .header { background: red; }